# How to show login page based on API response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I am consuming a Rails API using a client app written in Rails. If the user is not authenticated then i have to show the login page. I have created a structure of making API calls from only one Ruby class. Now from that Ruby class if the response status is 401 then i have to show login page. Is there any way of redirecting user to login page from my Ruby class?

Here is my client code

```
class Client
  def execute(method, url, params)
    response = case method
               when :get
                 HTTParty.get(url, query: params)
               when :post
                 HTTParty.post(url, body: params)
               when :put
                 HTTParty.put(url, body: params)
               when :delete
                 HTTParty.delete(url, body: params)
               else
                 nil
               end
    if response.status == 401
      # should redirect to login page
    else
      # Send result to caller which will parse it and send back to the controller action who called it
    end
  end
```

end

Comment: https://github.com/p8/redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by raising a custom exception and catching that in ApplicaionController.
From there i can redirect to login page easily.